# Creating dynamic queries with Entity Framework across multiple tables?

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to create search functionality across a couple of tables, following the pattern in [Creating dynamic queries with entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541234/creating-dynamic-queries-with-entity-framework)

I have 3 tables:

```
   People:
        pk ID
        varchar FirstName
        varchar LastName
        fk AddressMap_ID

   AddressMap:
        pk ID

   Address:
        pk ID
        varchar StreetName
        varchar StreeNumber
        fk AddressMap_ID
```

Multiple people can live at one address. I pass in a Search model, and populate the results property:

```
public class Search
{
   public string streetname { get; set; }
   public string streetnumber { get; set; }
   public string fname { get; set; }
   public string lname { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<Results> results { get; set; }
}
public class Results
{
   public int AddressID { get; set; }
   public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
   public string StreetName { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<PeopleResults> people { get; set; }
}
public class PeopleResults
{
   public int personID { get; set; }
   public string First { get; set; }
   public string Last { get; set; }
}
```

This works if I filter on an address, or name + address:

```
public void GetResults(Search model)
{
  Entities _context;
  _context = new Entities();

  var addr = from a in _context.Addresses
             select a;
  addr = addr.Where(filter => filter.StreetNumber == model.streetnumber);
  addr = addr.Where(filter => filter.StreetName == model.streetname);
  addr = from a in addr
         group a by a.AddressMap_ID into addrs
         select addrs.FirstOrDefault();

  var ppl = from p in addr.SelectMany(p => p.AddressMap.People) select p;
  ppl = ppl.Where(filter => filter.FirstName.StartsWith(model.fname));
  ppl = ppl.Where(filter => filter.LastName.StartsWith(model.lname));

  model.results = from a in addr
                  select new Results
                  {
                     AddressID = a.ID,
                     StreetName = a.StreetName,
                     StreetNumber = a.StreetNumber,
                     people = from p in ppl
                              select new PeopleResults
                              {
                                 First = p.FirstName,
                                 Last = p.LastName
                              }
                  };
}
```

But if I just try to filter on a name, it returns a cartesian join - every single address with all of the people that matched.

There are 3 ways to search: filtering on address only, filter on address + name, or filter on name only.

So if someone search for "123 Main", the results should be

```
123 Main St  SticksVille   Joe Smith
                           Jane Smith
                           Mary Smith

123 Main St  Bedrock       Fred Flintstone
                           Wilma Flintstone
```

A search for "J Smith 123 Main" should return just:

```
123 Main St  SticksVille   Joe Smith
                           Jane Smith
```

And a search for just "J Smith" should return:

```
123 Main St  SticksVille   Joe Smith
                           Jane Smith

456 Another St Sometown    Jerry Smith
```

Comment: The code you're showing doesn't actually compile, so it's not quite clear what you're going for. If you filter by an address, do you want `people` to include all people at that address? If you filter by a name, do you want to get all addresses that the people with matching names live at? And for each of those addresses, do you just want the `people` with matching names, or every person at that address?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: This is a simplified example, but I've updated the code so it should compile.

Comment: Please, elaborate on `results restricted to the addresses belonging to the selected people`.

Comment: @rcdmk: updated the question to show what type of results I'm hoping for.

Comment: Is this an existing database schema that you cannot change? I'm confused about this `AddressMap` table. Isn't this a many-to-many relationship between `People` and `Address`?

Comment: @Slauma: This is an existing schema, and this is just a simplified version.  It is sort of a many-to-many - many people can share one Address Map ID (this groups the people) and each address can have multiple representations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query looks "symmetric" to me with respect to people and addresses, it only gets "asymmetric" in the final projected result. So, my idea is to express this symmetry in the query as far as possible:

- Get a set (`IQueryable<Address>`, not executed at once) of addresses filtered by street name and street number
- Get a set (`IQueryable<Person>`, not executed at once) of people filtered by the beginning of first name and last name
- Join the two sets by `AddressMap_ID`. The resulting set of people and addresses contains only those pairs that fulfill the filter criteria for addresses *and* people. If one of the filter criteria for person or address is not supplied (the first and the third of your examples at the bottom of the question) the join happens on the unfiltered set of all people/addresses, i.e. the joined pairs contain always all people of the filtered address (or all addresses of the filtered people)
- Group the joined pairs of people and addresses by `Address.ID`
- Project the groups into your `Results` collection. The group key is the `AddressID`. `StreetName` and `StreetNumber` can be fetched from the first address in each group and the `people` are projected from the people in each group.
- Execute the query

The following code doesn't cover the case specifically that none of the four filter criteria is supplied. It works in that case but would just load all addresses with all people of those addresses. Maybe you want to throw an exception in that case. Or return nothing (`model.Results = null` or so), then just jump out of the method.

```
public void GetResults(Search model)
{
    using (var _context = new Entities())
    {
        // "All" addresses
        IQueryable<Address> addresses = _context.Addresses;
        // "All" people
        IQueryable<Person> people = _context.People;

        // Build a Queryable with filtered Addresses
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.streetname))
            addresses = addresses.Where(a => a.StreetName
                                              .StartsWith(model.streetname));
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.streetnumber))
            addresses = addresses.Where(a => a.StreetNumber
                                              .StartsWith(model.streetnumber));

        // Build a Queryable with filtered People
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.fname))
            people = people.Where(p => p.FirstName == model.fname);
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.lname))
            people = people.Where(p => p.LastName == model.lname);

        // Join the two Queryables with AddressMap_ID
        // and build group by Address.ID containing pairs of address and person
        // and project the groups into the Results collection
        var resultQuery = from a in addresses
                          join p in people
                            on a.AddressMap_ID equals p.AddressMap_ID
                          group new { a, p } by a.ID into g
                          select new Results
                          {
                              AddressID = g.Key,
                              StreetName = g.Select(ap => ap.a.StreetName)
                                            .FirstOrDefault(),
                              StreetNumber = g.Select(ap => ap.a.StreetNumber)
                                              .FirstOrDefault(),
                              people = g.Select(ap => new PeopleResults
                              {
                                  First = ap.p.FirstName,
                                  Last = ap.p.LastName
                              })
                          };

        // Execute query (the whole code performs one single query)
        model.results = resultQuery.ToList();
    }
}
```

I am unsure if I interpret the `AddressMap` table correctly as a kind of join table for a many-to-many relationship (`Address` can have many people, `Person` can have many addresses), but the code above yields the three results of the three queries in your example as expected if the tables are filled like so:

[image]

The `AddressMap` table isn't actually used in the query because `Addresses` and `People` table are joined directly via the `AddressMap_ID` columns.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like an approach like this would probably work:

```
IQueryable<Person> ppl = _context.People;
ppl = addr.Where(filter=>filter.First.StartsWith(model.fname));
ppl = addr.Where(filter=>filter.Last.StartsWith(model.lname));
var pplIds = ppl.Select(p => p.PersonId);

model.results = from a in addr
                where a.AddressMap.People.Any(p => pplIds.Contains(p.PersonId))
                select new Results {
                          AddressID = a.ID,
                          StreetName = a.StreetName,
                          StreetNumber = a.StreetNumber,
                          people = from p in a.People
                                   select new PeopleResults {
                                         First = p.FirstName,
                                         Last = p.LastName
                                   }
                };
```

Rather than basing the `people` property on the matching people, you want to base the entire address set on the matching people.

Comment: This omits the filter by address, and grouping people by address.

Comment: @chris: I omitted those parts of the code, because they don't need to change. Just replace the last portion of your code with something like what I posted. (I did notice one error, and I just fixed that.)

Comment: I had considered somthing like this, but if there are no filters on first or last name, pplIds is going to contain hundreds of thousands of IDs, and I'll have to execute 2 queries to get my results.

Comment: @chris: Nope, `pplIds` is an `IQueryable<int>`. It hasn't been evaluated yet. It just adds a `WHERE ... IN (...)` clause to the final query.