# How to Compare only date in Linq to Entity with Dynamic Query API?

Tags: c#-4.0, linq-to-entities

I have downloaded Microsoft Dynamic Query API. And using the dynamic query to filter the data using dates. I have written following query :-

```
Entities db = new Entities();
DateTime d = new DateTime(2014, 1, 17);
var lst = db.MSTPriorityS.Where("ModifiedOn == @0", d.Date.ToString()).ToList();
```

The result count, i am getting is 0. While there is data in the database table. 
Please advise what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think the problem is where you cast `DateTime` to `String` probably,
you can create your query step by step, and type safe, follow ['Creating dynamic queries with entity framework'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541234/creating-dynamic-queries-with-entity-framework)

Answer (score 0):

you can use lambda expression instead: `var lst = db.MSTPriorityS.Where(u => u.ModifiedOn == System.Data.Objects.EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(d))`

Comment: bcoz of some typical requirement of project i need to use dynamic query. so do u hv any work around for that?