# Filter values from DB by 4 parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have Experience entity
Here is it:

```
public class Experience:BaseEntity
{
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CreationDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string City { get; set; }
    public virtual int Price { get; set; }
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    public virtual int Rating { get; set; }
    public virtual double? Lat { get; set; }
    public virtual double? Lng { get; set; }
    public virtual DateTime? CompleteDate { get; set; }
    public virtual string CoverPic { get; set; }
    public virtual string Images { get; set; }
    public virtual string BroadcastingType { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsFinished { get; set; }
    public virtual bool IsConfirmed { get; set; }
    public virtual int CountryId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("CountryId")]
    public virtual Country Country { get; set; }
    public virtual string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual AppUser IdentityUser { get; set; }


    public virtual ICollection<Proposals.Proposals> Proposals { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Comments.Comments> Comments { get; set; }
}
```

I need to filter it by max and min price, rating and countryId.

So I wrote this method

```
public async Task<List<ExperienceListDto>> GetFilteredExperiences(FilterExperienceDto filterExperience)
    {
        var experiences = await _context.Experiences.Where(x =>
                x.Price >= filterExperience.MinPrice && x.Price <= filterExperience.MaxPrice &&
                filterExperience.MinPrice.HasValue && filterExperience.MaxPrice.HasValue ||
                x.Rating == filterExperience.Rating && filterExperience.Rating.HasValue ||
                x.CountryId == filterExperience.CountryId && filterExperience.CountryId.HasValue)
            .ProjectTo<ExperienceListDto>().ToListAsync();


        return experiences;
    }
```

But it filters only by min, max price. I want to filter it by all parameters. How I can do this?

Comment: I think your issue is that you're not using parenthesis. Group your conditions in parenthesis the way you want them logically. I think it doesn't branch like you expect it to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your code in this way to get the desired result:

```
IQueryable<Experience> query = _context.Experiences;

if (filterExperience.MinPrice.HasValue && filterExperience.MaxPrice.HasValue)
    query = query.Where( x => x.Price >= filterExperience.MinPrice && x.Price <= filterExperience.MaxPrice);

if (filterExperience.Rating.HasValue)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Rating == filterExperience.Rating);

if (filterExperience.CountryId.HasValue)
    query = query.Where( x => x.CountryId == filterExperience.CountryId);

var experienceList = query.ToList();
```

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5541505/1273882

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter only has value in request body.

```
var query  = await _context.Experiences.AsQueryable();

                    if(filterExperience.MinPrice.HasValue)
                        query = query.Where(x.Price >= filterExperience.MinPrice)

                    if (filterExperience.MaxPrice.HasValue)
                        query = query.Where(x.Price >= filterExperience.MaxPrice);

                    if(filterExperience.Rating.HasValue)
                        query = query.Where(x.Rating == filterExperience.Rating);

                    .
                    ..
                    ....



                    var expriences = query.ProjectTo<ExperienceListDto>().ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that the ||/OR statements could be messing your desired results because there might be different execution sequence of the conditional operators.

From your current code, you could do consecutive `.Where()` to filter them step by step

```
public async Task<List<ExperienceListDto>> GetFilteredExperiences(FilterExperienceDto filterExperience)
{
   var experiences = await _context.Experiences
.Where(x => x.Price >= filterExperience.MinPrice && x.Price <= filterExperience.MaxPrice && filterExperience.MinPrice.HasValue && filterExperience.MaxPrice.HasValue)
.Where(x.Rating == filterExperience.Rating && filterExperience.Rating.HasValue)
.Where(x.CountryId == filterExperience.CountryId && filterExperience.CountryId.HasValue)
            .ProjectTo<ExperienceListDto>().ToListAsync();


   return experiences;
}
```