# How to filter in Entity Framework Core without loading data on initialisation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm querying data from the database using Entity Framework Core using the following code:

```
CamicDbContext context = new CamicDbContext();

public override object Read(DataManagerRequest dm, string key = null)
{
    IQueryable<Country> query = context.Set<Country>();

    query = query.Where(x => x.IsDeleted == false);
    query = query.Where(x => x.Code == "PT");

    int count = query.Cast<Country>().Count();

    return dm.RequiresCounts ? new DataResult() { Result = query, Count = count } : (object)query;
}
```

When the `query` variable is declared, it seems that it is getting all items in the table (image 1), which seems wrong as it is inefficient with larger entities; therefore, I want to initialise the variable without getting data, build the query and then execute the query only when it reaches `return query` so the server will only query and return the items matching the filters.

I've tried multiple solutions. This one - [Creating dynamic queries with Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541234/creating-dynamic-queries-with-entity-framework) - is close to what I want to achieve, but the code in it has the same effect as the one I've mentioned above. I'm I missing something to use deferred execution?

I executed

```
IQueryable<Country> query = context.Set<Country>();
```

The result view shows all 264 entries in the table:

[image: Query initialisation result view]

Comment: I believe the results view will load `IQueryable`s when viewed in debug mode. If I'm not mistaken, during runtime it shouldn't query until you get the count.

Comment: Why do you have a `Cast<Country>()` call when you already have a `IQueryable<Country>` instance?

Comment: Declaring the variable `query` does not fetch the whole content of the table. The rows are only retrieved when the query is executed/iterated. So your code should already do what you are planning to do. If it doesn't, add a [mcve] which shows the problem you have.

Comment: *"The Result View shows..."* - noticed the message *"Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable"*? Enumerate means execute.

Comment: @Progman thanks for the heads up. Indeed the `cast` is not necessary. And thank you for the answer, I've missed that little information @IvanStoev.

Comment: You don't need to ask the DB for the count; you're going to retrieve 100 entities, that you can count (get the size of the collection of) on the client side. What *is* inefficient is asking the DB to run the query twice, once just so you can count the entities; be careful to avoid that

Comment: Why did you delete your old question, instead of answering comments and edit your question?

Comment: IQueryable<Country> query = context.Set<Country>(); is creating an IEnumerable because asqueryable is missing.  See my code below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When the query variable is declared, it seems that it is getting all items in the table (image 1),

It's not

> I'm I missing something to use deferred execution?

You are

Here's a screenshot from a test app after I turn logging on. In the code of the test app I create a context, build a query, and run it.. A couple of times in fact..

[image]

`x` is the context. If I open the debugger and expand the Orders "table" in the debugger tooltip there's a message at the bottom saying that looking at the results will enumerate the enumerable. If I enumerate, then the SQL will be executed:

[image]

There aren't any clauses on this - we're enumerating `Orders` which represents the entire table, so the SQL run is effectively `SELECT * FROM Orders`. There isn't any data in my Orders test table, which is why we see "no results" after the enumeration is complete, but if there were 1000 orders the debugger tooltip would have 1000 items in

---

The next line of code runs a LINQ `Where`:

[image]

This hasn't actually executed any SQL, but it's supplied a clause that EF *can* translate to SQL, so if you take a look in the `DebugView` property of the `IQueryable` returned by the `Where`, you can see the SQL that EF will form (`...WHERE Ref = ''`) when it's run.

Enumerating the queryable would actually run the SQL. Calling for a Results View in the debugger would enumerate, as would doing something like `ToArray`, `ToList`, `ToDictionary` (internally they all enumerate), or even a plain old `foreach` etc on your queryable. Whenever there's an enumeration, it triggers the running of the SQL.

If you use something like First, Count, Single then these trigger the execution of the SQL query also; they don't enumerate the entire set, they modify the SQL that is run but they *do* cause execution..

..which brings me to the point raised in the comments.

The code I've written enables EF to form a query with a WHERE clause, but then it asks the DB to execute it twice: once to get the Count (calling `.Count` causes a `SELECT COUNT(*) ... WHERE ..`)  and then again to get the actual data items (calling `ToList` does a SELECT columns ... WHERE ...`):

[image]

Given that you have to retrieve e.g. 100 items during the enumeration it would make more sense to retrieve them all and then get the local count of them; if you've stashed them in a list then the list will be tracking the Count

Keep in mind that when you're working with EF's sets and you haven't done anything to enumerate them already, the queryable you;re passing around and calling operations on essentially represents an SQL (or a partly built one) and every time you do something to it that will deliver data, it'll run the SQL

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can execute in one of two following ways: immediate or deferred. **Immediate** execution means that the data source is read and the operation is performed at the point in the code where the query is declared. All the standard query operators that return a single, non-enumerable result execute immediately where as a **Deferred** execution basically means that the operation is not performed at the point in the code where the query is declared. The operation is performed only when the query variable is enumerated.

Expending and viewing the `IQueryable` when debugging will act as immediate Query Execution, hence bringing that query in memory. in a non debugging environment this won't happen and the query will act as deferred query execution, meaning that it will actually be executed once the `Count()` method will get called

More about classification of Standard Query Operators by Manner of Execution can be found here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/classification-of-standard-query-operators-by-manner-of-execution

Comment: Although the Linq query will be executed/resolved when `Count` is invoked, a count-query will also resolve to count in SQL, so it will not fetch and return all objects from the table AFAIK. (edit: oh, now I see Caius' answer, who indeed states it as such)

Answer (score 0):

see https://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/using-asqueryable-with-linq-to-objects-and-linq-to-sql

1.When you use AsQueryable operator then further transformations are allowed: filtering, sorting, or aggregating
2.The additional lambda statements are converted to Expression trees.  I illustrate an expression filter using a lambda function.
3.If you use AsQueryable operator on a query that does not implement IQueryable and only implements IEnumerable< T >,than any transformations that you apply on the query would automatically fall back on IEnumerable specification.
4. IQueryable if deferred until a foreach is called and the expression tree is evaluated

```
 Product[] products =
                    {
                    new Product {ProductId=1, Name="Kayak",Category="Watersports",Price=275m, Company=new Company{ CompanyName="Abc Corp",States=new String[]{"Ut","Id" } }  },
                    new Product {ProductId=2, Name="Lifejacket", Category="Watersports",Price=48.95m, Company=new Company{ CompanyName="X Corp",States=new String[]{"Ca","Az" } }},
                    new Product {ProductId=3, Name="Soccer Ball", Category="Soccer",Price=19.50m, Company=new Company{ CompanyName="Y Corp",States=new String[]{"Tx","Wa" } }},
                    new Product {ProductId=4, Name="Corner Flag", Category="Soccer",Price=34.95m, Company=new Company{ CompanyName="Z Corp",States=new String[]{"Co","Wy" } }}
                     };
                  Transaction[] transactions =
                    {
                        new Transaction{ Name ="Bob Smith", ProductId=1, Cost=10.95M, Quantity=10},
                        new Transaction{ Name ="Dan Brown", ProductId=3, Cost=5.99M, Quantity=1}
                    };
    
    
    
                IQueryable<Product> query = products.AsQueryable<Product>();
    
                Expression<Func<Product, bool>> filter = x => x.Price > 100;
                 query = query.Where(filter);
    
                int count = query.Cast<Product>().Count();
    
                var result = query.Join(transactions,
                    product => new { product.ProductId },
                    transaction => new { transaction.ProductId },
                    (product, transaction) =>
                    new
                    {
                        CustomerName = transaction.Name,
                        ProductName = product.Name,
                        CompanyName = product.Company.CompanyName,
                        Price = product.Price
                    }) ;
    
                foreach (var item in result)
                {
                    _output.WriteLine($"Count: {count} Company: {item.CompanyName} Customer: {item.CustomerName} Product : {item.ProductName} Price : {String.Format("{0:C}", item.Price)}");
                }
```